# Automation with selenium (java) of angular app

Tags: java, angular, selenium, automation

We are using selenium (java) to test our web angular application.
we don't want to user x-path, but unique ids.

In our angular app we use generic components that are reused in a few places.
This causes the ids on the template of this generic component to not be unique. 
We thought to pass the unique id as an input to the generic component but we don't want to add unnecessary code just because of automation.

Are we missing something? Is there other solution besides an input to overcome this problem?

Comment: You dont want to use XPATH, you dont want to add ids , use generic components which generates same ids, but want to use only ids. Are you missing something.. yes. Either use XPath or modify the code.

Comment: just want to know that we are not missing anything..

Answer (score 0):

If it's not unique, it's not an id.

Then it's totaly OK to bind the id attribute to an `@Input` to ensure the uniqueness of the id embedded inside the component.

This code won't be unnecessary as it prevents the semantic of `id` attribute to be broken.

Comment: Correct, but we didn't want to add code to our app just because of automation.. I guess that we don't have any choice.

Comment: Do not consider this as adding code for your automation. It's more about preserving the semantic of id. Which will solve your problem.

Comment: Right, but without the automation I do not have any need in that id :)